# Java solrclient group query

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

I am building a chat like app and I am storing the chat conversation in Solr 6.5.1.
I have created a message collection and every document corresponds to a single message exchanged between two users. A document has a fromId and a toId like below.

[image]

I want to group the messages by toId and show a count of how many messages per conversation with a user. I am able to test it using admin UI like so.
[image]

But from my Java code using SolrJ I am unable to get the same result. Below is my code snippet

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.set("wt", "json");
query.setQuery("fromId:1234");
query.set("group",true);
query.set("group.field", "toId");
try {
        GroupResponse gRes = client.query(query).getGroupResponse();
        List<GroupCommand> groupCommands = gRes.getValues();
        List<GroupResult> grs = new ArrayList<>();
        for(GroupCommand gc : groupCommands){
            GroupResult gr = new GroupResult();
            gr.setCount(gc.getMatches());
            gr.setGroupText(gc.getName());
            grs.add(gr);
        }
        return grs;
    } catch (SolrServerException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    }
```

But this is not giving me both the groups , instead I am only getting one group with matched count as 6 .
Please help

Comment: Could you please try to print the underlying url, by using the below code snippet                                                       ClientUtils.toQueryString(query, false); I hope this will help

Comment: wt=json&q=fromId%3A1234&group=true&group.field=toId&group.limit=0&group.format=grouped

This is what it prints

Comment: If I am correct, by default group.limit should be 1, could you try by setting the group.limit to 1, then try again

Comment: i changed the limit to 1. That did not help either.

Comment: I am not sure then, could you try to add print statements to find out what are the data inside the middle of those objects which you are using

Comment: Thanks. I could trace the response format and figure out the changes needed to get the groups. I have answered.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. Below is the change required to my code in order to get to the groups.

```
QueryResponse gRes = client.query(query);
        GroupResponse grpR = gRes.getGroupResponse();
        List<GroupCommand> groupCommands = gRes.getGroupResponse().getValues();
        List<GroupResult> grs = new ArrayList<>();
        for(GroupCommand gc : groupCommands){
            List<Group> groups = gc.getValues();
            for(Group group : groups){
                GroupResult gr = new GroupResult();

                gr.setGroupText(group.getGroupValue());
                gr.setCount(group.getResult().getNumFound());
                grs.add(gr);
            }
        }
```